# Combinatorics Problem involving chessboard and squares

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

In how many ways can we choose two squares from a 8 by 8 chessboard given we cannot choose two squares that are in the same row or column?

There are 64c2 possible ways of selecting 2 squares on board. Subtract 8c2 *16 to subtract the options where there are two in the same row or column.
Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean "so that no two..."??? You are choosing only two to begin with!!!

Comment: As in you may select any 2 squares, except those that are in the same column and row

Comment: Well, this is confusing. You may as well replace "no two are" with "they are not". In any case, your answer looks correct to me.

Comment: I've edited it does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

Almost. The number of possibilities with two in one row or column are a little bit wrong: Fixing one square there are only 15 elements in the corresponding row/column the other one can not take, not 16. Which one did you count twice?

Comment: What OP did is $(\text{number of rows }+\text{ number of columns})\times(\text{ choose }2\text{ out of the }8\text{ squares in the chosen row or column})$.

Comment: Your suggestion (assuming that you meant $64\cdot15$) counts duplicates.

Comment: if you fix one square aren't there 14 others in the same row and column that it can't take? So -14*8?

Comment: there aren't any that we counted twice though? As two squares cannot be in the same row and column

Comment: No, there should be 15 as you also have to rule the case out that you pick the same square twice. This case is not ruled out when counting $64^2$ so you better do it at some place.

Comment: you can't pick the same square if you are using 64C2 though, i don't really understand what you're saying... so how is my solution wrong?